# A unique type of data conversion

Tags: c++

in the following code

```
tt=5;
   for(i=0;i<tt;i++)
    {

        int c,d,l;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&c,&d,&l);
        printf("%d %d %d %d",c,d,l,tt);
    }
```

in the first iteration, the value of 'tt' is changing to 0 automatically.
I know that i have declared c,d,l as int and taking input as long long so it is making c,d=0. But still, i m not able to understand how tt is becoming 0.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: but how is it possible?

Comment: When it writes outside of the `int` variables, it overwrites some other variable like `tt`.

Comment: How is what possible?  You have undefined behavior that means the compiler and do all sorts of things.

Comment: @TanujYadav, Since none of those variables are dynamically allocated, the complier is probably going to put them next to each other in memory.  Thtat's not guaranteed but it's pretty likely.  Of course adding variables, code, etc. to the program, or compile options, will likely change things.  That's why it's undefined.

Comment: It's behavior depends on sun and moon's position...if you get what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small, but obligatory announcement. As it was said in comments, you face undefined behavior, so

- don't be surprised by tt assigned to zero
- don't be surprised by tt not assigned to zero after insignificant code changes (e.g. reordering initialization from "int i,tt;" to "int tt, i;" or vice versa)
- don't be surprised by tt not assigned to zero after compiling with different flags or different compiler version or for different platform or for testing with different input
- don't be surprised by anything. Any behavior is possible.

You can't expect this code to work one way or another, so **don't ever use it in real program**.

However, you seem to be OK with that, and the question is "what is actually happening with tt". IMHO this question is really great, it reveals passion to understand programming deeper, and it helps in digging into lower layer. So lets get started.

### Possible explanation

I failed to reproduce behavior on VS2015, but situation is quite clear. Actual data aligning, variable sizes, endianness, stack growth direction and other details may differ on your PC, but the general idea should be the same.

Variables `i, tt, c, d, l` are local, so they are stored on [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). Lets assume, `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(long long)` is 8 which is quite common. Then one of possible data alignments is shown on picture (addresses grow from left to right, each cell represents one byte):

[image]

When doing `scanf`, you pass address of `c` (blue arrow on next pict) for filling with data. But size of data is 8 bytes, so data of both `c` and `tt` are overwritten (blue cells on the pict). For [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) representation, you always write zeroes to `tt` unless really big number is entered by user, while `c` actually gets valid data for small numbers.

[image]

However, valid data in `c` will be rewritten the same way during filling `d`, the same will happen to `d` while filling `l`. So only `l` will get nonzero value in described case. Easy test: enter large number for `c, d, l` and check if `tt` is still zero.

### How to get precise answer

You can get all answers from assembly code. Enable disassembly listing (exact steps depend on toolchain: gcc has `-S` option, visual studio has "goto disassembly" item in context menu while on breakpoint) and analyze listing. It's really helpful to see exact instructions your CPU is going to execute. Some debuggers allow executing instructions one by one. So you need to find out how variables are alligned on stack and when exactly are they overwritten. Analyzing `scanf` is hard for beginners, so you can start with the simplified version of your program: replace `scanf` with the following (can't test, but should work):

```
*((long long *)(&c)) = 1; //or any other user specified value
*((long long *)(&d)) = 2;
*((long long *)(&l)) = 3;
```